# Loading a trained crossValidation model in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, logistic-regression, cross-validation, bigdata

I am a new beginner in Apache Spark. I trained a LogisticRegression model using crossValidation. For instance:

> val cv = new CrossValidator()
>     .setEstimator(pipeline)
>     .setEvaluator(new BinaryClassificationEvaluator)
>     .setEstimatorParamMaps(paramGrid)
>     .setNumFolds(5)
>   val cvModel = cv.fit(data)

I was able to train and test my model without any error. Then I saved the model and the pipeline using:

> cvModel.save("/path-to-my-model/spark-log-reg-transfer-model")
>   pipeline.save("/path-to-my-pipeline/spark-log-reg-transfer-pipeline")

Up till this stage, the operations worked perfect. Then later on, I tried to load my model back for prediction on new data points, then the following error occured:

> val sameModel = PipelineModel.load("/path-to-my-model/spark-log-reg-transfer-model")

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Error loading metadata: Expected class name org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel but found class name org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.CrossValidatorModel

Any idea what I may have done wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to load CrossValidator with PipelineModel object.
You should use correct loaders...

```
val crossValidator = CrossValidator.load("/path-to-my-model/spark-log-reg-transfer-model")

val sameModel = PipelineModel.load("/path-to-my-pipeline/spark-log-reg-transfer-pipeline")
```

Answer (score 2):

To load a Cross Validator it should be

```
val crossValidator = CrossValidator.load("/path-to-my-model/spark-log-reg-transfer-model")
```

To load a Cross Validator Model use 
(Note: A Cross Validator becomes a Cross Validator model when you call fit() on CrossValidator)

```
val crossValidatorModel = CrossValidatorModel.load("/path-to-my-model/spark-log-reg-transfer-model")
```

Since you are trying to load a model, CrossValidatorModel.load would be the correct one.